# How to make vertical stack barchart in D3 Js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am creating a vertical stack bar chart in `d3.js`.  My bars are coming but there height is too large.  I think this is due to wrong scaling.

My code for graph is:

```
var localfinaldata = [];
var seriesData = "";
var xaxis = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {

        xaxis.push(data[i][j].orgunitname);
    }
}
xaxis = $.unique(xaxis);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var itemupdated = {};
    var localdata = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        var item = {};
        item["orgunitname"] = data[i][j].orgunitname;
        item["count"] = data[i][j].HeadCount;
        localdata.push(item);

    }
    var flag = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < xaxis.length; k++) {
        for (var l = 0; l < localdata.length; l++) {
            if (xaxis[k] == localdata[l].orgunitname) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
            else {
                flag = 0;
            }

        }
        if (flag == 0) {
            var item = {};
            item["orgunitname"] = xaxis[k];
            item["count"] = 0;
            localdata.push(item);
        }
    }


    // Call Sort By Name
    localdata.sort(SortByOrgunitName);
    itemupdated["datas"] = localdata;
    itemupdated["name"] = data[i][0].contype;
    localfinaldata.push(itemupdated);
}




  var margins = {
        top: 10,
        left: 1,
        right: 24,
        bottom: 5
    },
legendPanel = {
    width: 241
};
    var w = $('#contactChart').width();
    var h = $('#contactChart').height();
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 5, bottom: 30, left: 10 },
    width = w - margins.left - margins.right - legendPanel.width,
    height = 280 - margins.top - margins.bottom;
    var padding = { top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40 };

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .range(["#00aba9", "#da532c", "#B22222", "#228B22", "#FF00FF", "#1E90FF", "#D2691E"]);


$("#contactChart").html("");
var series = localfinaldata.map(function (d) {
    return d.name;
}),
 localfinaldata = localfinaldata.map(function (d) {
     return d.datas.map(function (o, i) {

         return {
             y: o.count,
             x: o.orgunitname
         };
     });
 }),
stack = d3.layout.stack();

stack(localfinaldata);

var localfinaldata = localfinaldata.map(function (group) {
    return group.map(function (d) {
        // Invert the x and y values, and y0 becomes x0
        return {

            x: d.x,
            y: d.y,
            y0: d.y0
        };
    });
}),
    svg = d3.select('#contactChart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right + legendPanel.width)
        .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')'),
   yMax = d3.max(localfinaldata, function (group) {
       return d3.max(group, function (d) {
           return d.y + d.y0;
       });
   }),

    yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, yMax])
    .range([height, 0]),

    orgunitname = localfinaldata[0].map(function (d) {
        //  return d.y;
        return d.x;

    }),

    xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(orgunitname)
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1),
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom'),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left'),


    groups = svg.selectAll('g')
        .data(localfinaldata)
        .enter()
        .append('g')

      .style('fill', function (d, i) {
          return color(series[i]);
      }),
    rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
        .data(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter()
        .append('rect')

     .attr('y', function (d, i) {
         //return yScale(d.y);
         return yScale(d.y);
     })
       .attr('x', function (d,i) {

            // return xScale(d.x0) + 135;
           return xScale(d.x);
        })


        .attr('height', function (d) {
            //return yScale.rangeBand();
            return Math.abs(yScale(d.y)-yScale(d.y0));
        })

        .attr('width', function (d) {
            // return xScale(d.x);
            return xScale.rangeBand();
        });


groups.selectAll('text.label')
    .data(function (d) {
        return d;
    })
   .enter()
  .append("text")
   .text(function (d) {
       if (d.y == 0) {
           return null;
       }
       else {
           return d.y
       }
   })
  .attr("class", "text")
.attr("x", function (d) {

    return xScale(d.x) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
})
.attr("y", function (d) { //return yScale(d.y) + yScale.rangeBand() / 2; 
    return yScale(d.y0) + yScale(d.y);
})
  .attr("dy", "0.5em")
  .attr("dx", "0.5em")
    .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("font", "bold 12px Arial")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")




svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + height + ',0)')
    .call(yAxis)
     .selectAll("text")
                         .attr("x", "10em")
                         .attr("y", "0em")
 .style("text-anchor", "end")
                        .attr("font-family", "Arial")
                        .attr("font-size", "13px");

$('.axis path').css("fill", "none");


series.forEach(function (s, i) {
    svg.append('rect')
       .attr('fill', color(series[i]))
       .attr('width', 20)
       .attr('height', 20)
       .attr('x', width + margins.left + 160)
       .attr('y', i * 24 + 150);
    svg.append('text')
        .attr('fill', 'black')
         .attr("font-size", "11")
        .attr('x', width + margins.left + 181)
        .attr('y', i * 24 + 164)
        .text(s);

});
```

data is in format:

```
data = [{
       datas:[{
            orgunitname: 'ABCD',
            count: 1

        }, {
            orgunitname: 'XYZ',
            count: 6

        },
        {
            orgunitname: 'XYZ',
            count: 0

        }],
        names: 'Local'
    },
        {
        datas:[ {
            orgunitname: 'ABCD',
            count: 7

        }, {
            orgunitname: 'XYZ',
            count: 8
            },
            {
            orgunitname: 'mno',
            count: 7

        },],
            names: 'Temporary '
            }
        ]
```